Is there a mistake in proof of proposition 4.1.2. regarding algebras of sets in Dudley's Real Analysis and Probability?
It looks to me as though there's a mistake in proof of proposition 4.1.2. in Dudley's "Real Analysis and Probability" (2002 edition). The proposition is stated as (I have omitted parts irrelevant to this question)
"Let $X$ be any set and $B(1), \ldots, B(n)$ any subsets of $X$. $[\ldots]$ Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the collection of all intersections $\cap_{1 \leq i \leq n} C(i)$ where for each $i$, either $C(i) = B(i)$ or $C(i) = X \setminus B(i)$. $[\ldots]$"
Then in the proof it said
"Any two elements of $\mathcal{C}$ are disjoint (for some $i$, one is included in $B(i)$, the other in $X \setminus B(i)$). The union of $\mathcal{C}$ is $X$. Thus the set of all unions of members of $\mathcal{C}$ is an algebra $\mathcal{B}$."
The last sentence is the one I have trouble with. To my understanding an algebra should contain the empty set. However, I can't figure out how "the set of all unions of members of $\mathcal{C}$" should necessarily contain the empty set. I have also devised a counterexample. If $X = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \}$, $B(1) = \{ 1, 2 \}$ and $B(2) = \{ 2, 3 \}$, then $\mathcal{C}$ contains intersections $B(1) \cap B(2)$, $(X \setminus B(1)) \cap B(2)$, $(X \setminus B(1)) \cap (X \setminus B(2))$, $B(1) \cap (X \setminus B(2))$. Thus $\mathcal{C}$ contains the sets $\{ 1 \}$, $\{ 2 \}$, $\{ 3 \}$, and $\{ 4 \}$. Now the set of all unions of members of $\mathcal{C}$ does not contain the empty set. Unless the set all of unions of members of some collection is somehow implicitly always assumed to contain the empty set, but that does not really make sense to me. Is there really a mistake here or am I missing something?

A nullary union refers to a union of 0 sets and it is by definition equal to the empty set.

To expand on the previous comment, it depends on how one interprets the "set of all unions of members of $\mathcal C$. If a union can be an empty union and we define the empty union to be the empty set, then all is good.

Ok, so the set of all unions of members of some collection is assumed to contain the union of zero sets. These are the kinds of technicalities that cause lots of headaches for me:D Thanks for the quick answer though! Helps a lot!

I agree that $\varnothing=\bigcup_{A\in\varnothing}A$, but I don't think that this requires any sort of separate convention: by definition, if $\mathcal C$ is a collection of sets, then the union $\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal C}$ of the sets in $\mathcal C$ equals $U={x\mid \exists A\in\mathcal C(x\in A)}$. If $\mathcal C=\varnothing$, then there is no $x$ such that $\exists A\in\mathcal C(x\in A)$, and hence $U=\varnothing$.
